# Seam 2.1.1: build using Maven 2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, seam, web-frameworks

I'm interested to move a project based on Seam 2.1.1 from Ant to Maven, to integrate some tools in the build process (like testability explorer and others)

Question is: you recommend it? I've read (in the few sites with useful information about this subject) that is quite pain in the back to use Seam 2 with Maven, while others say is worth the effort. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Maven 2 in a number of projects of my own and at work.  Maven can be fiddly to set up and debug but it definitely does save a lot of hassles with dependency management.  It is really a love hate relationship.

But overall, I think Maven is definitely a benefit to my projects.  Once configured correctly, it is great for managing the dependecies I have in my projects.

I definitely think it's worth the effort.